# Removing border from nested tr

Tags: html, css

I was hoping I could get some help with removing a table border from an "nested" (not sure if that is the proper terminology).

Here is what I have so far:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
            <th>Six</th>
            <th>Seven</th>
            <th>Eight</th>
            <th>nine</th>
            <th>ten</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="schedule-header">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.schedule-header {
background: #0062a1;
color: white;
border: none;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

Now I am getting all the styling I want except for the border: none; style.

Basically my plan is to use jquery to pop in this nested table when a dropdown arrow is clicked on the table row above, revealing relevant data.

Ok so I fixed the code and added the collapse to my css and it doesnt seem to be fixing it.

Comment: Well, that's invalid HTML. A `<tr>` has the following permitted parent elements: "A `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element." (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

Comment: As @DavidThomas points out, you cannot nest a `<tr>` directly in a `<tr>` - I can't even predict what a browser would make of it. Fix your HTML first, then fix the CSS.

Comment: Ok so I fixed the code and added the collapse to my css and it doesnt seem to be fixing it.

Comment: There is never a valid reason to nest tables.

Comment: Assuming you added the `border-collapse: collapse` (as you say you did) to the correct element's styling (that of the `<table>`), it seems to work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lqejf7yb/); or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a small function that will attach a display function to each sibling row that has a button, but I think you should do some more tutorials first, as you have many mistakes that just create more confusion.

Try doing some of the Tutorials on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) to improve your CSS, HTML and eventually JQuery.

Good Luck ;)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .more_info {
        background-color: #0062a1;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        display:none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    button {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #0062a1;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function (){
        var info_row = $(this).parent().parent().next();
        info_row.toggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td><button>i</button></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="more_info">
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td><button>i</button></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="more_info">
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-collapse: collapse;` to the CSS of your table:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;   
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gosmad90/)